# Proper Way to Update a Node's Path Programatically in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, path

I am editing a node's path programatically like this in Drupal6:

```
$node = node_load(3);
$node->path = 'some/new/path';
node_save( $node );
```

That of course works, but the old alias remains. What's the best way to do this? I see no path functions or pathauto functions to remove the old alias. Or do I simply need to remove the alias using SQL on the url_alias table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shoud use [path_set_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--path--path.module/function/path_set_alias/6)

To update a path, take a look at [path_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--path--path.module/function/path_nodeapi/6), e.g. :

```
path_set_alias('node/' . $node->nid, $node->path, isset($node->pid) ? $node->pid : NULL, isset($node->language) ? $node->language : '');
```

Comment: But that doesn't remove the old alias does it?

Comment: OK, so I changed it to use the path functions instead of saving the path property on the node, but is there an internal function I can use instead of straight delete SQL on the url_alias table, as path_set_alias doesn't appear to remove the old alias.

Comment: `path_set_alias` will update an alias (no need to delete it) if you provide node pid. Answer updated.